# Cannot put image inside div

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to put a profile image next to names, however they won't go next to the text, instead go below the div containing the text. I'm not sure if I'm being blind, but I can't find how to fix it.

To clarify, I'm attempting to put the images that are on the page next to the text (The white next to 'main, the wolf next to 'joe' and kenny next to 'kenny').

EDIT: I found the stupidly easy solution. Flagged for deletion!

Comment: You should add code to this page so others can learn from it in the future

Comment: The code should be here so that it is not susceptible to link rot.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;float:left;">
   <img alt="" src="" width="50" />                     
    your text here
</div>
```

Also if you want text will be in center put text in `<Div>` element like this:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;float:left;">
   <img alt="" src="" width="50"/>
</div>
<div>
   your text here
</div>
```